# Sending JSON object using rest

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to create this:

```
 [
        {
            "id":"1",
        },
        {
            "id":"3",
        },
        {
            "id":"5",
        },
        {
            "id":"6",
        },
        {
            "id":"9",
        },
    ]   



    Person = {
                "id" : Id
            }; 

    PersonArray.push(Person);
    tempPersonJson['PersonList'] = JSON.stringify(PersonArray);
```

This is my output:

```
List = "[{\"id\":\"12\"},{\"id\":\"10\"},{\"id\":\"9\"},{\"id\":\"8\"},{\"id\":\"7\"},{\"id\":\"6\"},{\"id\":\"5\"},{\"id\":\"4\"},{\"id\":\"3\"},{\"id\":\"2\"},{\"id\":\"1\"},{\"id\":\"12\"},{\"id\":\"10\"},{\"id\":\"9\"},{\"id\":\"8\"},{\"id\":\"7\"},{\"id\":\"6\"},{\"id\":\"5\"},{\"id\":\"4\"},{\"id\":\"3\"},{\"id\":\"2\"},{\"id\":\"1\"}]";
```

API complains with this:

Call Body
Expected body: Content-Type is application/json but body is not a parseable JSONParse error on line 21: ...value": true },] ---------------------^ Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got ']'
Watchout for malformed JSON. Expected data media type ('null') does not match real media type ('application/json').

Update, JSON sent to server:

```
[{"id":"12"},{"id":"10"},{"id":"9"},{"id":"8"},{"id":"7"},{"id":"6"},{"id":"5"},{"id":"4"},{"id":"3"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"1"}]
```

Comment: How is `tempPersonJson['PersonList']` used? `JSON.stringify(PersonArray)` itself will *always* return valid JSON.

Comment: Stored in a model (backbone js),  later get out of the model pass into an api.

Comment: Could you please post a jsfiddle with the complete code?

Comment: ..And with the *actual* relevant/final JSON supplied to the API, and how; how it is stored is irrelevant (except if it ruins the JSON which is why the *actual* final JSON is important) as is the code currently shown which can be ignored per JSON.stringify being "good".

Comment: What you claim to be trying to create (at the top of your post), isn't valid JSON to start with. You have a rogue extra `,` at the end of your array.

Comment: added my JSON sent to server at the end of post

Comment: The JSON you are sending is valid. The problem is on the server end.

Comment: The code you show does not match up to the error message, show the code that has/deals with whatever contains `value": true },]`

Comment: thanks guys, that was the problem, the additional comma!

Answer (score 0):

So just taking a stab at it...>I created a jsfiddle for you....fixing some missing variables.

```
var   Person = {
            "id" : '1'
        }; 

var PersonArray =[];
PersonArray.push(Person);
var tempPersonJson = [];

tempPersonJson['PersonList'] = JSON.stringify(PersonArray);

console.log('tp',tempPersonJson);
```

[Working fiddle click here](http://jsfiddle.net/6g3qzk5v/)